# Grunt task - wait for server (selendroid) to be ready

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, server

I want to wait for a server to be ready, then run a task on top of it

EDIT:
I've got *some* of this figured out. I am properly filtering for my string. However, how can I keep this running in the background, and have it terminate when a grunt sequence is complete?

Consider
`grunt common server spec-e2e`
This will run the common tasks, run the grunt server, then (without stopping the server) runs the next task on top. After all of this is complete, it turns off the server automatically.

That's the kind of functionality that I'm trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

A couple important points that I learned:

- Processes started from node - e.g. `require('child_process').spawn(...)` - will continue to run for all subsequent grunt tasks (they won't be closed once the single task completes).
- Once grunt is finished running the sequence of tasks, it will terminate all spawned processes.

Therefore, the command `grunt selendroid:selendroid.jar spec-e2e` - where the `selendroid` task starts a server - will keep the server running until after the `spec-e2e` task completes.

The code for my `selendroid` task is:

```
grunt.registerTask('selendroid', 'Start selendroid server', function (appLocation) {
    var done = this.async();
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Selendroid took too long to start');
        done(false);
    }, 30000);

    function checkLoaded(data) {
        data = data.toString();
        if (data.indexOf('Selendroid standalone server has been started on port') > -1) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            done();
        }
    }

    if (typeof appLocation === 'undefined') {
        console.log('App to test not set, aborting...'.red);
        done(false);
    }

    var cmd = require('child_process').spawn('java', ['-jar', 'selendroid.jar', '-app', appLocation]);
    cmd.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        checkLoaded(data);
    });
    cmd.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        checkLoaded(data);
    });
});
```